# How to deduce the 2d Fermi integral with drift velocity?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, plasma-physics

I read the article https://arxiv.org/abs/2106.01296, and i see in the eq. (3) an expression for the local electron density using a 2D Dirac distribution with drift velocity,

$$f_{\alpha 0} (r,p,t) = \dfrac{1}{1+e^\dfrac{\varepsilon_\alpha-pv-\mu}{k_BT}}$$

how is it possible to derive that equation? I have tried and have gotten nowhere.

I hope you can help me.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.